# R: Calling multiple elements in a list

Tags: r

I have saved multiple ggplots in a list and would like to plot them using the cowplot package. But to do this you have to call each entry in the plot_grid function.

Example code:

```
plot<-vector("list",length=6)
data<-vector("list",length=6)

for(i in 1:6){
  data[[i]]<-data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
 plot[[i]]<-ggplot(data=data[[i]])+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))
}

plot_grid(plot[[1]],plot[[2]],plot[[3]],plot[[4]],plot[[5]],plot[[6]])
```

I am looking for an easy way to call the multiple entries of the list into the plot_grid function. If possible, it would also be neat to be able to call some specific entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `do.call`:

```
library(gridExtra) # note that I'm using grid.arrange from the gridExtra library
do.call("grid.arrange", c(plot_list, ncol=2, nrow=3))
```

with `plot_grid`:

```
library(cowplot)
do.call("plot_grid", c(plot, ncol=2, nrow=3))
```

FYI don't call an object with a reserved name, instead of `plot` use something like `plot_list` as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.
And I usually don't use objects with reserved names, it was just to use as an easy example code :)

Comment: Great solution, thank you. I tried `library(cowplot); do.call("plot_grid", c(plot, ncol=2, nrow=3,labels=LETTERS))`, but was not able to add labels. Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `purrr::invoke` (`purrr` is part of the core tidyverse):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

invoke(plot_grid, plot)
```

Note: `invoke` is a wrapper around `do.call`, so this is really a variation of @RLave answer: the above is the same as

```
do.call(plot_grid, plot)
```